# Mail Script - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='

Tags: php, html

I am trying to setup a simple mail script from an html form that includes a dropdown list but on the line where I declare the selected variable I am getting an error message:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='........

My html form includes the dropdown list as follows:

```
<select name="buying-selling" id="buying-selling">
<option value="none_selected" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
<option value="buying_property">Buying a Property</option>
<option value="selling_property">Selling a Property</option>
<option value="sales_updates">Sales Updates</option>
</select>
```

And at the top of my email script I have:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['Submit']!="")
{
$name=$_POST['name'];
$emailaddr=$_POST['emailaddr'];
$buying-selling=$_POST['buying-selling'];
$message=$_POST['message'];
```

.......followed by all the mailheaders data

But when I try and process the form I am getting the "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='" for the line that contains the POST['buying-selling'] element.

Is there a different syntax for declaring items from a dropdown list?

I am new to coding for mail scripts so any advice would be very welcome.

Many thanks

Comment: [Read about variables](http://php.net/variables) (especially the *Basics* page).

Answer (score 4):

`$buying-selling` is not a valid variable name. Try `$buying_selling` instead.

Comment: Plus the OP would have to change `select name="buying-selling"` to `select name="buying_selling"`

Comment: @Fred, Why would he need to change the select's attribute name to "buying_selling" from "buying-selling"?

Comment: @vinodadhikary Ok, Kolink didn't specify exactly what needs to be changed. Is it `$buying-selling=$_POST['buying-selling'];` or `$buying-selling` or `$_POST['buying-selling'];` ?

Comment: @vinodadhikary and `Kolink` - If post variable needs to be changed, then `select name="buying-selling"` would also need to be changed to reflect the name change, no? What am I missing here?

Comment: @Fred, no, the problem here is PHP variable name.  PHP does not allow variable names with hyphens(http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php).  The html attribute value with hyphen is perfectly fine, and on the php side array keys can have hyphens.

Comment: @vinodadhikary I understand that, but how else will `$_POST['buying_selling'];` <= (with underscore) get the data from `name="buying-selling"` <= (with hyphen) then?

Comment: @vinodadhikary Scratch my last comment, I just figured it out. Personally I never used hyphens, because I don't like them. Maybe a good thing all this time. Never knew about a hyphen causing problems like that.

Comment: @Fred, nice one :).  Wish this answer was elaborated more after all these comments!

Comment: @vinodadhikary Yes I agree. Well, at least I figured it out by myself. It took me 10-15 seconds, but I got it and now it's going to "stick". Thanks for shedding some light on the subject and pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @vinodadhikary Just a quick last note. Funny that http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php does not make any mention on the (illegal) use of hyphens/dashes.

Comment: @Fred, it's there, anything other than `[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*` is invalid.

Comment: @vinodadhikary Got it, thanks. I just got confused with the dashes in `[a-z]` etc. and was literally looking for the word "hyphen" or "dash", that's why it didn't click. Thanks again.

Comment: @Fred - Many thanks for the info - I have updated the forms and they work a treat now.