# Unexpected '=' in php

Tags: php, syntax-error

I am getting a strange error in my php code, and I can't figure out why!

The error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' on line 9`

```
<?php
session_start();

$name = $_POST['Contact-Name'];
$address = $_POST['Contact-address'];
$email = $_POST['Contact-Email'];
$phone = $_POST['Contact-Phone'];
$program = $_POST['Program-Name'];
$date-requested = $_POST['date-requested'];

$timestart = $_POST['program-start-time'];
$timeend = $_POST['program-end-time'];

$timestart-format = $_POST['starttime-format'];
$timeend-format = $_POST['endtime-format'];

$full-start-time = $timestart." ".$timestart-format;
$full-end-time = $timeend." ".$timeend-format;


//the book king hours
$mon-thurs-hours = array("10:00 AM", "11:00 AM", "12:00 PM", "1:00 PM", "2:00 PM", "3:00 PM", "4:00 PM", "5:00 PM", "6:00 PM");
$friday-hours = array("10:00 AM", "11:00 AM", "12:00 PM", "1:00 PM", "2:00 PM", "3:00 PM", "4:00 PM", "5:00 PM", "6:00 PM", "7:00 PM", "8:00 PM");
$saturday-hours = array("10:00 AM", "11:00 AM", "12:00 PM", "1:00 PM", "2:00 PM", "3:00 PM", "4:00 PM", "5:00 PM", "6:00 PM");

//find the day of the week and save to $dayofweek
$date = new DateTime();
$timestamp = date_timestamp_get($date-requested);
$dayofweek = date( "w", $timestamp);

//if sunday
if($dayofweek == 0){
echo "You choose Sunday!";
die('Sorry, the book king is closed on Sundays!');
}

//if monday, tues, wed, thurs
if(($dayofweek == 1)||($dayofweek == 2)||($dayofweek == 3)||($dayofweek == 4)){
echo "You choose day ".$dayofweek."!";
//see if bk is open at the specified times
if (in_array($full-start-time, $mon-thurs-hours)) {
  echo "Start time is okay!";
    }
    if (in_array($full-end-time, $mon-thurs-hours)) {
      echo "End time is okay!";
    }
}

//if friday
if($dayofweek == 5){
    echo "You choose day ".$dayofweek."!";
//see if bk is open at the specified times
if (in_array($full-start-time, $friday-hours)) {
  echo "Start time is okay!";
}
    if (in_array($full-end-time, $friday-hours)) {
      echo "End time is okay!";
    }
}

//if saturday
if($dayofweek == 6){
echo "You choose day ".$dayofweek."!";
    //see if bk is open at the specified times
    if (in_array($full-start-time, $saturday-hours)) {
      echo "Start time is okay!";
    }
    if (in_array($full-end-time, $saturday-hours)) {
      echo "End time is okay!";
    }
}

?>
```

I'm not sure if you need *all* that code, or just the first 9 lines, but I posted it all just in case!
I really appreciate your help with this!

Comment: How is the variable on that line different from the preceding ones? What do you use the different symbol for in PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mail Script - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294546/mail-script-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18050071)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in `$date-requested` identifier. You can not use `-` in identifier. Identifier may contain only letters, digits, and underscope (`_`) and must start with letter or underscope.

So it is interpreted as expression (variable `$date` minus constant `requested`), and the whole line as an assigment to that expression, which make no sense to PHP processor. That's why you get such strange error message.

Use valid variable name like `$date_requested`

Comment: Thanks! Never even noticed that a `-` was disallowed. How about in the `$_POST` variables? Will it cause an issue there?

Comment: `-` is a mathematical operator. obviously you cannot use it in variable names.... but it's fine for form elements.

Comment: `$_POST` array, just like all other PHP arrays, allow any string to be a key. So `$_POST['date-requested']` is valid, but I would not recommend to intentionally use such string keys, not beeing valid identifiers, just because later you may want to use `extract` on the array or convert it to object.

Comment: Thanks guys, I appreciate your help and support! :)

Answer (score 1):

`$date-requested` is not a valid variable name (cannot include a hyphen), use `$date_requested` or similar instead.